# is there a way to set heading for a Point?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have heading that i get with this `computeHeading(from:LatLng, to:LatLng)`, latlng of one point and distance to second point(in meters) is there a way using these three things to get latlng of second point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From google docs [Navigation Functions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Navigation)

*Given a particular heading, an origin location, and the distance to travel (in meters), you can calculate the destination coordinates using `computeOffset()`.*